# how can I run IntelliJ's live edit without running the entire application?

Tags: intellij-idea

If I'm working on a java application, and I want to just edit some HTML templates, I'd like to be able to see the changes I'm making in realtime.  IntelliJ gives me links to launch the page in different browsers ([preview output](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/editing-html-files.html#ws_html_preview_output)), but this doesn't perform realtime updates, so I'm not sure what value that adds over just opening the template manually.  All the documentation for the Live Edit plugin appears to be under the category of [debugging javascript](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html).  Following their [example](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html#debugging_js_on_built_in_server_example) doesn't appear possible as the "run" is not an option in the context menu - I assume it's only for particular types of projects.

Can anyone tell me how I can get IntelliJ to provide realtime output for html editing?

Answer (score 0):

As it's clearly stated in [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/live-editing.html), Live Edit is available only during a JavaScript debugging session. You can't make it work while previewing HTML page in browser. So implementing hot reload on a server end is the only solution